# Is there any way to make Linq To Sql generate row wrappers that default to value comapre instead of reference compare?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

The classes that Linq to Sql generates to represent a row from a table default to reference equality what calling Equals()

We have many tables and writing an override statement for every Equals() method would take too long and instantly become impossible to maintain.

Is there any way to make Linq To SQL project class wrappers with Equals() overridden to calculate value equality?

Comment: How would it know value equality if don't override Equals?

Comment: May I should say is there any way to make Linq To SQL project class wrappers with Equals() overridden so I don't have to?

Comment: So like automatically use the PK for Equals.   That would be cool.   I hope you get an answer.

Comment: Actually I was thinking compare every property that represents a field, but either way I think I'm going to have to write my own generator. XSLT time methinks